# How do I handle collections with @thymesVar?

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

If I have:

`<!--/*@thymesVar id="someCollection" type="java.util.List"*/-->`

How would I specify the type of objects in the collection?

I don't see anything on SO or the Idea docs about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oh, it's as simple as specifying the class in the declaration:

`<!--/*@thymesVar id="someCollection" type="java.util.List<com.domain.my.Bean>"*/-->`